# ftp_nb_fput(): TYPE is now 8-bit binary with ftp_ssl_connect

Tags: php, ftp, ftps

Assume you have the following code:

```php
// ...
$conn_id = ftp_ssl_connect($ftp_server);
ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);
ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);
$fp = fopen($source_file, 'r');
$ret = ftp_nb_fput($conn_id, $destination_file, $fp, FTP_BINARY);
while ($ret == FTP_MOREDATA) {
   // ...
   $ret = ftp_nb_continue($conn_id);
   // ...
}
// ...
ftp_close($conn_id);
```

In my setup this code produces the following warning

```
ftp_nb_fput(): TYPE is now 8-bit binary
```

If I run the same code **without** `ftp_ssl_connect($ftp_server);` but with `ftp_connect($ftp_server);` the code runs without a warning.

Am I using ftps with php in the wrong way or what is the problem? (PHP-Version on running system is: 7.1.13).

Comment: Can you upload that file using any FTP client running on the same machine as your PHP code?

Comment: With an other user it actually works

Comment: What *"other user"*?

Comment: That one my chef put in ;-)